# 240 volt outlet is not delivering full 240 after electricity went off

Tags: 240v

Our electricity popped off, smelled metallic. Now 240v outlet registering less power. Dryer only beeps and does not run.

Comment: Is that true for all appliances or just the dryer?  Are the hot water heater and range working ok?

Comment: Like how much less? Does each leg still deliver 120v?

Comment: When you mean "your electricity popped off" are you saying a breaker tripped?  Did you have to do anything to the breaker box to get it to turn back on?